# Is there a more functional way to add n elements to the beginning of a list?

Tags: f#

I have a function that receives an integer and returns a binary list of that number:

```
let DecimalToBase2 (n:int) = 
        Convert.ToString(n,2)
        |> Seq.map (fun c -> int c - int '0')
        |> Seq.toList

DToB 23  -> [1; 0; 1; 1; 1]
DToB 511 -> [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1]
DToB 512 -> [1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
```

I'm always expecting a list of length 10, I need to append '0''s to the beginning of the list.

I know that F# Lists are immutable, but what I don't know if this code I'm using is the best way to do it.

How does 'yield' work?

Is it creating multiple lists and appending them or just one at runtime?

```
let DecToBase2 n =
    let xx = DecimalToBase2 n
    let result =
        [
            for i in xx.Length .. 9 do
                yield 0
            done
        ] @ xx
    result

D 23  -> [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1]
D 511 -> [0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1]
D 512 -> [1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more functional approach. It might not be the shortest way, but when you are trying to get a handle on thinking functionally that shouldn't be what you are going for. What's we'll do is use one function to calculate the bits then another to pad the result to desired length. Both will do this recursively. `loop` appends number's lowest magnitude bit to the list and then divides by two and repeats until there are no bits left. Then `pad` prepends 0's until the list is the desired size (10):

```
let d2b n =    
    let rec loop n lst =
        if n > 0 then loop (n >>> 1) ((n &&& 1) :: lst) else lst

    let rec pad lst size filler =
        if (List.length lst < size) then pad (filler :: lst) size filler else lst

    pad (loop n []) 10 0
```

Your attempt is using what is called a list comprehension and is a fair way to do it. `@` is often considered a code smell since it is sometimes used to add a single item to the end of a list, where its performance is really poor (it is O(N) where N is the length of the list on left). However, in this case, I don't think it's any worse than what I've got above.

There are several shorter ways to do it, not sure if they are any better performance-wise. You could use a list comprehension to just test each bit like so:

```
let d2b n = [for i = 9 downto 0 do yield (n >>> i) &&& 1]
```

or use a single helper function to test the length (honco's suggestion in comments)

```
let d2b n = 
    let rec loop n lst = 
        if List.length lst < 10 then loop (n >>> 1) ((n &&& 1) :: lst) else lst
    loop n []
```

Comment: The approach and the performance is way better using bitwise operators and recursive functions. Thank you.

Comment: Could be better done using a single "loop" and testing on the "desired size" rather than the value of the number converted.